# chrome is showing different font on different PCs

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

i'm having problem, because font is showing different font on different PC, example on image:
![enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbhcv.jpg

PC's are using same version of Chrome, so where could be problem?

ty

Comment: You sure about zoom % ?. If not Just Press Ctrl + 0 to reset the zoom %.

Comment: I tested this, but no changes...it's very weird :/

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome's Official Troubleshooter might help you to overcome it.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95290?hl=en

Here is the link to adjust fonts and languages :

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95416

Make sure that the second pc has the adequate fonts

Here is the microsoft's link to troule shoot it https://support.microsoft.com/kb/314960/en-us

Hope, it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you checked it only on two PCs, one reason could be that one of them is not able to download the font style.